# Spring boot annotations

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm a beginner with spring boot so i need to ask some questions:

```
1 - what is difference between @async and @service("async")
2 - what is @transactional do ? 
3 - what is the difference between maven project and spring-starter-project ?
```

thanks for all ,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Question 1

The annotations don't have any relation.

[@Async](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) marks a method as a candidate for asynchronous execution. Can also be used at the type level, in which case all of the type's methods are considered as asynchronous.

[@Service](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) annotation serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.

If you use @Service("async") you are creating a Bean with name "async", nothing to do you asynchronous processing.

### Question 2

[@Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) is used on methods that should span operations (like DB operations)  in a single transaction. Let's say for example that you have a method that is going to save 3 records to different tables on DB and you have it annotated with @Transactional. Then all the 3 operations are going to be commited only if the method completes successfully. If the last operation fails, then nothing is commited to DB.

### Question 3

A maven project can be any type of Java project. A Spring project is a project that uses components from Spring framework.
If you want to create an automatic Maven project with Spring dependencies take a look at [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/). It will automatically generate the files for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,,